# MVC maintaining dates in textboxes using datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, datepicker

In MVC.NET, I have one page with "To Date" and "From Date" textboxes having Bootstrap datepicker attached to them.

1. On page load, I want today's date selected in datepicker by default and displayed in the textbox as well.

Beside I have Go button on same page which redirects to another page which uses FromDate and ToDate filtered data.


2. On this second page I have back button of type "button" (not submit) which when clicked should return to page one with having FromDate and ToDate selected values in textboxes.

My issue is,I have set "FromDate" and "ToDate" textbox values as today's date in document.ready()

However if I select another date and click on "GO" which redirects to page two but when clicked on back button on page 2, Page one ToDate and FromDate are filled with today's date (due to document.ready())

How do I achieve to show today's date on page load and for rest of the times maintain selected Dates in textboxes when back is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page get refreshed when you coming back on first page from second page.

So you have to carry whatever data you have entered on first page when you will hit Controller/Action you have to take this data in **TempData** and whenever you will come on the fist page you have to set this data again in that that text boxes.

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: I have one issue I want to have fromdate and todate displayed as today's date in textbox as well as in datepicker on page load.Without setting them in document.ready() (as this creates problem when i try to select another date). How can I achieve this

Comment: Try with this it will show current date and you can change your date as well : **$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());**
**$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        "setDate": new Date(),
        "autoclose": true
});**